# Add controller option removed after upgrading MVC4 to MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, upgrade, asp.net-mvc-5

I have started a new basic Razor website, as a sort of 'clean slate' for the update.

I followed [the tutorial that everyone recommends](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2), and it had completed without an issue.

Unfortunately, now, I have no option to add a controller.
When I right click on the `Controllers` folder and move to <kbd>add</kbd>, there is no *Controller* option. There is also no *Controller* option in <kbd>add</kbd>><kbd>new item</kbd> or <kbd>add</kbd>>from template.

Can anyone please help me get this functionality back? I've been browsing for solutions for a while now, and mine seems pretty unique.

Comment: Try creating a new MVC5 project, open the project file with Notepad. There is a set of projecttype GUIDs in there, make sure your upgraded project matches that list.

Comment: VS2012 doesn't give me the option to create a new MVC5 project.

Comment: You did install the MVC5 web tools for Visual Studio 2012, right? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed that. Very big oversight.. Attempting to install now, will update with any results.

Comment: @jessehouwing that was the issue! Woops... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the following items:

1. [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)
2. Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012 ([Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids) | [Direct Download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/8/6A894BC6-3C60-42B5-8246-5EF7918FD852/AspNetWebTools2013_1Setup.exe))

Then follow [this tutorial to upgrade your MVC 4 project to MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2).

Finally make sure your project has the following ProjectTypeGuids:

```
 <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

In MVC5 the option you're looking for might be hidden under the <kbd>Add Scaffold</kbd> menu option. See the release blog [post for more information on MVC5 scaffolding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx).