# How do I get the “Add Controller” and “Add View” menu options in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, upgrade, asp.net-mvc-5

I upgraded my solution from MVC 4 to MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2012 using [this tutorial.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) In the last step I removed the ProjectTypeGuid for MVC 4 from my `.csproj` file.

Now the problem is that I don't see <kbd>Add Controller</kbd>, <kbd>Add View</kbd> in Visual Studio when I want to create new Controllers/Views.

I read [this answer for MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) so I know I need to get the correct ProjectTypeGuid for MVC 5 in order to regain that functionality. I was wondering if anyone knows what that is so that I can add them to my `.csproj` file?

Comment: @SLaks that option is not there when I right click on the controllers folder.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20397312/736079

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install the following items:

1. [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)
2. Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012 ([Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids) | [Direct Download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/8/6A894BC6-3C60-42B5-8246-5EF7918FD852/AspNetWebTools2013_1Setup.exe))

Then follow [this tutorial to upgrade your MVC 4 project to MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2).

Finally make sure your project has the following ProjectTypeGuids:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>
    {349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}
</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

In MVC5 the option you're looking for might be hidden under the <kbd>Add Scaffold</kbd> menu option. See the release blog [post for more information on MVC5 scaffolding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx).

---

Some information gathered from: http://forums.asp.net/t/1950055.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I will add another link that show some other steps that I had to do to make this work.

Comment: Blogged: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/12/upgrade-your-existing-aspnet-mvc4.html

Comment: My Project file has these GUIDs, but I still don't have the option to add Controller/View. There is no Add Scaffold menu option either. No Controller/View templates appear in "Add New Item" menu.

Comment: I've been working on MVC5 for a while, but the shortcut keys and options for AddView keep disappearing on me :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are still using Visual Studio 2012 and are looking for a way to have intellisense for your views made for razor 3, if you want to add a new view and a new controller with the proper menu entries in visual studio you probably noticed that with things don’t work as they should.

Simply install the following 2 components:

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012 (link to direct download)
Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012