# Still Missing Context Menu Options View/Controller/Scaffold in VS2012/MVC5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a new windows install and installed VS2012 from scratch and have an existing MVC4 project that was upgraded to MVC 5 prior to my machine rebuild.

I am not able to get the context menu options to work for the options to:

1. Add Scaffold (when r-click on project)
2. Add View (when r-click on the Views folder under the Areas/AreaName/folder. It does work on the root level View folder)
3. Add Controller (when r-click on the root folder/Controllers folder. I do have an option for a Web API 2.0 controller but not a stardard MVC controller.)

I have tried everything presented in this solution:

1. [How do I get the “Add Controller” and “Add View” menu options in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479383/how-do-i-get-the-add-controller-and-add-view-menu-options-in-my-asp-net-mvc)

...but no luck.

I do have an option to create a New MVC Empty Project and did so and tested the context menus there...same issues.

Any other ideas?