# Scaffolding an external model in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have a simple domain model in an external assembly. This model uses DTOs to communicate with a couple service classes. It does not use Entity Framework.

In Visual Studio 2012 I could select my DTOs in the Add View dialog and scaffold strongly-typed views for them.

[image: Visual Studio 2012 scaffolding]

However, the DTOs are not showing in the Add View dialog in Visual Studio 2013.

[image: Visual Studio 2013 scaffolding]

Strongly-typed views I create manually work just fine, so the issue isn't that Razor / MVC can't see or use my DTOs. The issue is just with the scaffolding.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've come up with a hack. I created a class in the Models folder with the same properties as my DTO and then created Views from it. Then I went into each of the views and changed the model back to my DTO. I deleted the class in the Models folder when I had all the views I needed. Still looking for a real solution.

Comment: @Cory Is this a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/20480300/495455?

Comment: Take a look at [Visual Studio 2013 Pro Add View does not show a referenced Data Access Class Library Model in the Model Class drop down list.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809839/visual-studio-2013-pro-add-view-does-not-show-a-referenced-data-access-class-library-model-in-the-model-class-drop-down-list). The proposed workaround is to use a project reference.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Not quite; I have the "Add Controller" and "Add View" menu options, but the dialog that comes up only lists classes from the solution in the model class drop-down it seems, not external assembly references. I realize this is probably to keep the list from being a million classes long, but it seems like the dialog should let you type in a fully qualified class name (which you can, but the OK button remains disabled) and still scaffold it.

Answer (score 0):

So your DTO lives somewhere other than the project namespace or the .Models namespace.  The dropdown has an affinity to pull classes for strongly typed views from there. I realize that your DTOs might live in another assembly, and what your hack was, but is there a way to recompile them into the MvcDemo.Models namespace in the other assembly and declare a partial class in the models namespace in the MVC project?  That may not be the ideal answer, and if you don't like the idea, I'll gladly delete my answer.

Comment: Partial classes cannot span assemblies, even if they share the same namespace, so unfortunately I don't think this will work.